# Querying for Members in specific Campaigns

Tags: salesforce-id, campaign, campaign-member

I am trying to find campaign members for campaigns executed in last 2 years (not via Apex), in order to migrate this data. Using Jitterbit.

I have tried couple different queries (from developer console) and can't seem to get the right query.  Campaign is a lookup on CampaignMember, so should I not be able to use the __r notation to access?

```
SELECT Id, CampaignId, ContactId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, FirstRespondedDate, HasResponded, IsDeleted, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LeadId, Status, SystemModstamp 
FROM CampaignMember
where CampaignId = Campaign__r.id and Campaign__r.CreatedDate >= LAST_N_YEARS:2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

SELECT Id, CampaignId, ContactId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, FirstRespondedDate, HasResponded, IsDeleted, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LeadId, Status
FROM CampaignMember 
WHERE CampaignId IN (SELECT Id FROM Campaign where CreatedDate > 2013-04-01T00:00:00Z)

?

Comment: please upvote if you like it